# gperftools not installing -lprofiler on Mac after installing it with brew

Tags: c++, profiler, pprof, gperftools, gperf

Recently I wanted to profile my cpp code and came across gperftool, but there aren't really clear instructions on how to use it with Mac. So far I have run `brew install gperftools` and wanted to compile my simple cpp file which just outputs "Hello world!". I run `g++ main.cpp -lprofiler -o main` but get error `ld: library not found for -lprofiler`. I really appreciate it if you could guide me or should me a tutorial where it's easy to follow. Thanks :)

Edit: Currently I am using MacOS with new M1 chip (not sure if that can cause any issue)

Comment: Here is a page to learn about gperftools: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=Profiling_with_GPerfTools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So brew didn't install the binaries and that's it.

Follow these steps if you are having a hard time making it work

1. clone https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools
2. run ./autogen.sh
3. run ./configure
4. make && sudo make install
5. you should see some path where the binaries where installed, if you wanna take a look at it to make sure (mine was `/usr/local/lib`)
6. Profit

Answer (score 0):

I found you can also use the `-L$(brew --prefix gperftools)/lib` flag to tell g++ where to look for the libraries if you don't want to install with make.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option. You can identify brew package location by calling

> brew info gperftools

```
==> gperftools: stable 2.13 (bottled), HEAD
Multi-threaded malloc() and performance analysis tools
https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gperftools/2.13 (101 files, 4.5MB) *
...
```

Then you only need to specify the location of the library and header files for the compiler. This can be done using CMake this way:

```
target_include_directories(Target PRIVATE /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gperftools/2.13/include)
target_link_directories(Target PRIVATE /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gperftools/2.13/lib)
target_link_libraries(Target PRIVATE profiler)
```